# AngularJs code for database operations in phonegap

Tags: angularjs, cordova

AngularJs code for CREATE,INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE operations using Phonegap. The database can be sqlite or mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use http://brian.io/lawnchair/ for my storage needs with my angular phonegap apps and it works really well.  Check out the following blog post for an example of how this works. http://www.glenntaylor.co.uk/local-storage/phonegap-and-offline-storage-part-2-lawnchair#.VDrnr75Jk20

Comment: Will Haley: Its suitable for me.!